# Monkey-patch a module imported by a TON of files (unit tests)

Tags: python, monkeypatching, unit-testing

I probably have an [XY problem](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/XyProblem) here, so answers that provide a better solution to my actual problem are welcome just as much as answers that advise how to do the stupid thing I want to do.

The X problem is, I have a VERY large test suite using [Python's `unittest` module](https://docs.python.org/2/library/unittest.html). Let's say hundreds of individual `test_<foo>.py` files. I know how to discover them using `unittest.discover()`. However, this puts them all in one big test suite. I want three (or four or five) subsets: e.g., the `frontend` test suite and the `backend` test suite. For simplicity you may assume that the subsets are mutually exclusive.

I don't want to manually list out all the `frontend` tests in one big "table of contents"; I want to keep using `discover()` (so that newly added frontend tests are picked up automatically and the "table of contents" never gets stale).

So my thought is to use decorators in some way. E.g., my existing testcase module

```
import unittest

class TestButtons(unittest.TestCase):

    def test_simple(self):
        self.assertTrue(True)
```

would become

```
import unittest
import MySuites

@MySuites.FrontEndTest
class TestButtons(unittest.TestCase):

    def test_simple(self):
        self.assertTrue(True)
```

and then, having `discover()`ed all the test cases, I could filter that big suite into my smaller suites by examining the classes' attributes in some appropriate way.

The Y problem is, this solution requires me to `import MySuites` into every one of my hundreds of test files. I'd like to avoid that diff, if possible. In fact, ideally I would be able to write

```
import unittest

@unittest.FrontEndTest
class TestButtons(unittest.TestCase):

    def test_simple(self):
        self.assertTrue(True)
```

using some kind of monkey-patching. However, again, I don't want to have to `import` some other module in hundreds of files; I just want `unittest` to "do what I want" without me having to tell it hundreds of times.

Is this possible? How would a native Python speaker solve my problem(s)?

Answer (score 1):

I'd subclass unittest.TestCase, and then have my test code import the modules with the subclass.

```py
# module: quuxunittest.py
import unittest

class FrontEndCase(unittest.TestCase):
    pass

class BackEndCase(unittest.TestCase):
    pass
```

And then you can write tests as you would normally, and rely on test discovery to ignore the tests that it shouldn't run.

```
import quuxunittest

class TestButtons(quuxunittest.FrontEndCase):
    def test_simple(self):
        self.assertTrue(True)
```

You'd then want to subclass the unittest discovery code to take advantage of this.